# Ubuntu Server 12.0.4 VSFTPD connection timeout using external IP

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd, port-forwarding

I am having a problem connecting to my Ubuntu 12.0.4 server with `vsftpd` using my external IP. Connecting using the local IP is successful. I am using FileZilla for the ftp client.

I know there is a bunch of stuff online about this but nothing has fixed my problem: I have:

- port 21 forwarded in my router
- the vsftpd.conf file is correct I believe.
- The only thing I can think is that I don't have any passive configurations set, but not sure if I need them.

I can provide my vsftpd.conf if needed, and also I can take screenshots of my router config to make sure that is correct also.

*If somebody could please help me with this that would be great.*

Answer (score 0):

If you use `pasive mod` you need `port 20` also be forwarded on router to your server.

Comment: My ISP might be blocking port 21, I have also port forwarded port 20 without having any passive mode switches set, I will contact my ISP about the port being blocked, because if they have it blocked nothing I do will matter.

Answer (score 0):

If your ISP is blocking port 20 and 21, edit the `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and add the following 2 parameters:

```
ftp_data_port=xx
listen_port=yy
```

where xx and yy are numbers between 1-1024 that are not blocked by your ISP.  Quirk: `connect_from_port_20` must still be enabled, though xx will now be the new port used.

(you must also change your FTP client to reflect this change)

Source: `man vsftpd.conf`